# Google calendar api access with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am kind of confused about the google api, and in particular the google calendar api.  It seems every example I find wants the user to connect and return through a return URL.  All I am wanting to do is grab information in the background with google calendars api, display data, and even create data.  I would be willing to do this with Javascript/JSON or through PHP preferably.

Here is the example i found:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/GoogleClientApi/Google_Client.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/GoogleClientApi/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php';

$scriptUri = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType('online'); // default: offline
$client->setApplicationName('My Application name');
$client->setClientId('INSERT HERE');
$client->setClientSecret('INSERT HERE');
$client->setRedirectUri($scriptUri);
$client->setDeveloperKey('INSERT HERE'); // API key

// $service implements the client interface, has to be set before auth call
$service = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) { // logout: destroy token
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
    die('Logged out.');
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) { // we received the positive auth callback, get the token and store it in session
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) { // extract token from session and configure client
    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
    $client->setAccessToken($token);
}

if (!$client->getAccessToken()) { // auth call to google
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header("Location: ".$authUrl);
    die;
}
echo 'Hello, world.';
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  If anyone is curious on how this works whatever google API you are using you will first need to allow access via you browser, unless you already have an access token.  After this you can pull any information you need from their library.